# MariaDB Check String Length Performance

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

Can anybody explain the impact on the performance of the query when we are using the `Length()` function to check the length of string (`Varchar`) data?

```
SELECT LENGTH(FIRST_NAME), FIRST_NAME FROM MIT_STUDENTS;
```

This is my query above for the `length()` function. Can anyone explain the performance of `length()` function in the above query?